# Angular - Open a modal as separate component - without using ng-modal

Tags: angular, typescript

I have componentB which HTML have Modal bootstrap code. From ComponentA, I need to open the the componentB in componentA.

The popup is not shown in the UI. On inspecting the page, the component is getting loaded but it is not shown in UI.

```
<app-root> 
  <app-a>
    <app-b></app-b>
  </app-a>
</app-root>
```

NOTE: I dont have any CSS in both the components

ComponentA.html:

```
<button (click)="popup()">Open</button>
<app-b *ngIf="openModal" [openModal]="true" ></app-b>
```

ComponentA.ts:

```
 popup(){
    this.openModal = true;
  }
```

componentB.html:

```
<div *ngIf="openModal" id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

componetb.ts:

```
@Input('openModal') openModal : boolean
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please describe what issue are you facing ?

Comment: The popup is not shown in the UI. On inspecting the page, the component is getting loaded but it is not shown in UI.
<app-root>
<app-a></app-a>
**<app-b></app-b>** // this is loaded.
</app-root>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make modal visible add `show` and `d-block` classes.

In *componentB.html* Change your modal div to:
`<div *ngIf="openModal" id="myModal" class="modal fade show d-block" role="dialog">`

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjqr1k)

**But hold on**
This is not how modals are supposed to work. I would recommend using [ngx-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) instead or check out [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) to manipulate classes better way.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a regular component as a modal**, create your  component for example ModalComponent, in the constructor you need to add this variable  : `public activeModal: NgbActiveModal`

you can use this instruction to close an opened Modal `this.activeModal.close()`
In the caller/parent component add these two variables
a reference to the modal component  `modalRef: NgbModalRef`

and in the constructor add this variable `private modalService: NgbModal`
you can call the modal component like this `this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);`
you can pass any variable to the Modal component like this `this.modalRef.componentInstance.variable = variableContent;`

Don't forget to add the Modal component in entryComponents Array, in the app.module `entryComponents: [ModalComponent]`

Comment: I don't know if he is even using that library, but if he isn't he should be